# Can I use a pandas categorical variable as the left hand side of a statsmodels formula?

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I have a dataframe with the following dtypes

```
strata_id    category
treatment    category
status       category
dtype: object
```

I’m trying to fit a logistic regression with the statsmodels formula api, like this

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
model = smf.logit('status ~ 0 + strata_id + treatment', data=df)
```

I get an error when I call `model.fit()` because the formula api (powered by patsy) converts my categorical `status` column to an (N, 2) array of one-hot encoded vectors, but statsmodels expects an (N,) array of integers.

I know there are plenty of ways to work around this, such as generating design matrices directly with patsy and preprocessing the matrices before giving them to statsmodels.

However, is there a way to make the statsmodels formula api do the right thing here?

Python 3.6.4
Pandas 0.23.0
Statsmodels 0.5.0

Comment: How to fix this on the statsmodels side is still an open question https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2733 That is, statsmodels is just getting the transformed data from patsy and doesn't know how it created the endog and exog arrays from the original data or pandas DataFrame.

Comment: "2 unit tests, 0 integration test"  Sometimes improvements in separate packages don't integrate well for some use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the context, I was afraid that was the case. I’m a little surprised Patsy doesn’t have a way to request this kind of categorical coding. Oh well

Comment: If you write up your comment as an answer I’ll accept it